# Use PSF font in X11 terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, x11, fonts

I want to use a specific console font (`/usr/share/consolefonts/Uni3-Fixed16.psf.gz`) in a X11 terminal emulator (for example Terminator or gnome-terminal).

- I've stumbled over [similar](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=392354) questions, but nothing about PSF, just PCF. How can I install a PSF font, or convert it to something that can be used?
- If this does not work for whatever reason, is there a font that comes close to the font mentioned? I've tried out many and this is the best I've found.
- Of course I have also scanned with Google, finding [some](http://www.lowing.org/fonts/) [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming) [compilations](http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts). For me Unifont looks closest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with the PSF font format, but google revealed [1] which seems to imply it is a bitmapped font format (pixel based).

Using the tools from [1], convert to a .FON and then follow along in answers of [2] to create a .ttf

However, it might be easier to look into other options.
If you are looking for tiny, fixed width console fonts you should check out the proggy fonts [3]

1: http://www.seasip.info/Unix/PSF/index.html

2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750124/how-to-convert-a-bitmap-font-fon-into-a-truetype-font-ttf

3: http://www.proggyfonts.net/download/

Comment: Actually the proggy fonts are pretty nice!